# spring mvc sending email got error (check images)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

This is my home controller under the controller package

EmailController.java

```
package org.convey.example.controller;
import org.convey.example.email.EmailSender;
import org.convey.example.model.EmailMessage;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bi[enter image description here][1]nd.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import java.util.Map;


/**
 * $LastChangedDate:  $
 * $LastChangedBy:  $
 * $LastChangedRevision:  $
 */
@Controller

public class EmailController {

     ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("emailConfiguration.xml");
        EmailSender emailSender=(EmailSender)context.getBean("emailSenderBean");


        final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmailController.class);


        @RequestMapping(value="/emailForm",method= RequestMethod.GET)
        public ModelAndView displayEmailForm(Map<String, Object> map)
        {

            logger.debug(" setting up the Email form ");

            ModelAndView view=new ModelAndView("EmailFormView");

            //setting up the  required parameter value in the request scope for CommandName parameter
            map.put("email", new EmailMessage());

            return view;

        }



        @RequestMapping(value="/sendEmail",method= RequestMethod.POST)
        public ModelAndView sendEmailUsingGmail(@ModelAttribute("email")EmailMessage email){


            logger.debug(" ********************* ready to send the email **********************");
            logger.debug(" receiver email address [{}]", email.getReceiverEmailAddress());
            logger.debug(" email subject [{}]", email.getSubject());
            logger.debug(" email body [{}]", email.getMessageBody());

            ModelAndView view=new ModelAndView("EmailView");

            view.addObject("emailAddress",email.getReceiverEmailAddress());
            emailSender.sendEmail(email);
            logger.debug(" ********************* email was sent **********************");

            return view;

    }
}
```

This is my second class under email package

EmailSender.java

```
package org.convey.example.email;

import org.convey.example.model.EmailMessage;
import org.springframework.mail.MailSender;
import org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage;

/**
 * $LastChangedDate:  $
 * $LastChangedBy:  $
 * $LastChangedRevision:  $
 */

public class EmailSender {

     private MailSender mailSender;

        public void setMailSender(MailSender mailSender) {
            this.mailSender = mailSender;
        }


        public void sendEmail(EmailMessage emailMessage){

            SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();

            message.setTo(emailMessage.getReceiverEmailAddress());
            message.setSubject(emailMessage.getSubject());
            message.setText(emailMessage.getMessageBody());
            //sending the message
            mailSender.send(message);

    }

}
```

This is my third class under the model package

EmailMessage.java

```
package org.convey.example.model;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

/**
 * $LastChangedDate:  $
 * $LastChangedBy:  $
 * $LastChangedRevision:  $
 */
@Component
public class EmailMessage {


     private String receiverEmailAddress;
        private String subject;
        private String messageBody;


        public void setMessageBody(String messageBody){

            this.messageBody=messageBody;
        }

        public String getMessageBody(){

            return this.messageBody;
        }

        public void setReceiverEmailAddress(String receiverEmailAddress){

            this.receiverEmailAddress=receiverEmailAddress;
        }

        public String getReceiverEmailAddress(){

            return this.receiverEmailAddress;
        }


        public void setSubject(String subject) {

            this.subject=subject;
        }

        public String getSubject(){

            return this.subject;
    }
}
```

This is my EmailFormView.jsp page under which email form created

EmailFormView.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Email Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<form:form commandName="email" method="POST" action="sendEmail">

    <p>Email Form </p>
    <br/><br/>

    Receiver Email
    <form:input path="receiverEmailAddress"/>
    <br/><br/>

    Subject
    <form:input path="subject"/>
    <br/><br/>

    Message Body
    <form:input path="messageBody"/>
    <br/><br/>

    </br>
    <input type="submit" value="Send Email" />

</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my EmailView.jsp page that the display the message to the sender that the email has successfully send

EmailView.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Email was successfully sent to the ${emailAddress}</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my applicationcontext.xml file

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <!-- the below bean is configured to define external property file for defining property values for the application.
           the following bean is used for configuring a resource bundle for this application based on different locales-->
    <!--<bean id="messageSource"-->
     <!--class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">-->
    <!--<property name="basename" value="classpath:properties/messages" />-->
    <!--<property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>-->
    <!--</bean>-->


</beans>
```

This is my email-servlet.xml file

email-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- this will scan the @Component models defined in the given package (including sub packages) and it will automatically create instances.
         if you have used @Component annotation, it is not required to define the beans  in the XML configuration files -->
    <!-- Discover POJO @Components -->
    <!--<context:component-scan base-package="org.convey.registration" />-->

    <import resource="applicationContext.xml"/>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="handlerMappingC"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property
                name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop
                        key="/emailForm">
                    emailController
                </prop>

                <prop
                        key="/sendEmail">
                    emailController
                </prop>

            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="emailController" class="org.convey.example.controller.EmailController"/>

</beans>

This is my web.xml file

web.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name><param-value>/resources/log4j.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>


    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>email</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>

        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>email</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

This is my index.jsp page

index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Bhushan</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2> <a href="/email/emailForm">Click here to Load Email Form</a></h2>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my pom.xml file

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.spring1</groupId>
    <artifactId>mypackage</artifactId>
    <name>SpringMvcEmail</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <java-version>1.6</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>3.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                 </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>   

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
   <!-- Java Mail API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- @Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>       
        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>email</finalName>
    </build>

</project>
```

***MY question is that, I want to style to my Message Body like font, bold, text size how do i changes in my program???***

Comment: Where is the error message?

Comment: Please post your stacktrace that you receive on error. At this point the topic is unclear.

Comment: Ask another question about your edit. It's not related to your first question, and styling your message body isn't a Spring problem. It's a CSS issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do not insert images for showing your error. Check the stacktrace in your IDE console and copy-paste it here.

Beside that, you have a 404 error, that means the ressource requested is not available because you send a bad URL. You send this `email/emailForm`and there is any handler in your controller to handle your request. In your case, you should just send `/emailForm`.

**EDIT**

I missed the error that you made, this is an error that beginners often make.
I looked again your image and you have in your address bar this : `localhost:8080/email/emailForm`. If you take a look on your browser address bar when you visit stackoverflow website you have this : `stackoverflow.com/...` Here `stackoverflow.com` is the domain, in other words the root of the application.

In your case, the domain is missing, you should have something like `localhost:8080/yourDomain/email/emailForm`.

You have several ways to add it in the URL :

a) Add it manually

b) Use JSTL tag like this  `<a href="<c:url value="/email/emailForm"/>">....</a>` it's my favorite solution because the `<c:url >` tag add automatically the root of the application.

c) Get request context path : `<a href="${request.contextPath}/email/emailForm">....</a>`

d) Write this `<a href="email/emailForm">.....</a>` instead of `<a href="/email/emailForm">...</a>`. In fact the slash changes things and `/email/emailForm` is not the same as `email/emailForm`. I let you make the test, you will be surprised.

These should help you.

Beside that, please revise the configuration of your application, in a SpringMVC application, you have 2 main contexts : the root context and the servlet context.
In your configuration you have only one and I love Spring so much to let you do that. This could cause problem if you want to add other features like managing security in your application.

Comment: In your stacktrace there isn't any exception. Did you change the URL?

Comment: No I am not changed in url

Comment: Change this `<a href="/email/emailForm">Click here to Load Email Form</a></h2>` to `<a href="/emailForm">Click here to Load Email Form</a></h2>`

Comment: Please make clear your configuration and put beans in their correct place (in their context). Your application do not have a root context.

Comment: Get the root of your application when you send your request. So try this '<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/emailForm">Click here to Load Email Form</a>'

Comment: I edited the answer. Take a look and let me know if it works.

Comment: when I run the program and click on this link   'Click here to Load Email Form' then I got following  error -----

HTTP Status 404 - /mypackage/WEB-INF/view/EmailFormView.jsp

type Status report

message /mypackage/WEB-INF/view/EmailFormView.jsp

description The requested resource is not available.
Pivotal tc Runtime 3.2.2.RELEASE/8.5.6.B.RELEASE     I changed the url which is guided you '<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/emailForm">Click here to Load Email Form</a>' but get same error

Comment: It's a spring-maven project so you should have a tree like bellow. Verify if the view's folder is `view or views`

"mypackage
  |___src
          |___main
                   |___webapp
                               |___WEB-INF
                                           |____views
                                                        |__EmailView.jsp
                                                        |__index.jsp "

Comment: I am going to set <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/emailForm">Click here to Load Email Form</a> this and it will work fine..thanx

Comment: You welcome. I hope you understood how this part work.